# Remove SQL Server Replication Subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication

I have a problem with the replication on my machine where I am stuck with a number of subscriptions showing in SSMS that do not exist.  I have tried deleting them using the UI in SSMS and also using some T-SQL...but no luck.  The publications don't even exist any more (they were on the same machine).

Any ideas on how I could remove them?

More info:
This is the situation I appear to be in where there are 3 subscriptions (that SSMS will not let me look at because 'they do not exist').

---

[image]

Comment: What T-SQL have you tried? Have you tried the nuclear option of [`sp_removedbreplication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188734.aspx)?

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't work either.  I have just updated the post with an image to show you what SSMS can see!  My box is PC007-W7 which was the location of the subscription and the publications so I don't know how to get rid of a subscription for a publication that doesn't exist!!

Comment: Oh...I just restarted my SQL Server and running that sp_removedbreplication seems to have done the trick!! Thanks for that, can you make it an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Sorry about this...correction, they went temporarily but came back!!! :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have some orphaned metadata in the distribution database.  If you're no longer publishing any data you might want to try [Disabling Publishing and Distribution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147921.aspx) to remove the orphaned publications and subscriptions.

Comment: This is how I fixed it in the end.  I went a bit further becuase I had a bit of time so I un-installed replication and deleted the distributor database.  All works now!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I find it odd that `sp_removedbreplication` didn't work... maybe try [`sp_dropsubscription`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184385.aspx), and include the `ignore_distributor` parameter:

```
declare @yourServer sysname
set @yourServer = @@servername

exec sp_dropsubscription 
    @publication='UD-ForCMS',
    @article='all',
    @subscriber=@yourServer,
    @destination_db='CMS',
    @ignore_distributor=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found sometimes that the system view objects created by the replication can be left hanging. Stopping replication from being manually rebuilt. My solution was to manual drop the system view syncobj. I recommend always dropping the subscriptions and the publication before dropping publication properties above since I've found items get left behind leaving for long term problems.

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3: There is already an object named
>   'syncobj_0x3437324238353830' in the database. Msg 21745, Level 16,
>   State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_articleview, Line 272 Cannot generate a
>   filter view or procedure. Verify that the value specified for the
>   @filter_clause parameter of sp_addarticle can be added to the WHERE
>   clause of a SELECT statement to produce a valid query. Msg 3931, Level
>   16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_articleview, Line 401 The current
>   transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a
>   savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction. Warning: The distribution
>   agent job has been implicitly created and will run under the SQL
>   Server Agent Service Account.